# I have error Call to a member function getData() on null l/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php:501 in supro theme

Tags: magento2, products, multi-vendor

I have error main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /home/bigroadusa/web/bigroadusa.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Image.php:501 in debug and system log. This error show when i go to vendor products page.
Exception log empty.

Screenshot vendor products page

[image]

link leads to first product

Comment: did you add any log print in any file?

Comment: No, log saved only on default file

Comment: did you put log print code in any file?

Comment: Hm, no, I need?

Comment: If, so where???